# Prevent Divs From Overlapping In Responsive Layout

Tags: css, responsive-design, resize, overlapping

I am trying to prevent two side by side divs I have from overlapping in responsive layout.

Here is my html:

```
    <div class="image"><img src="images/misc/libertyXSmall.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="storyWrapper">
    <div class="headline">THIS IS A TEST HEADLINE TO SEE HOW EVERYTHING 
    WORKS ON THIS NEWS LIST PAGE!</div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
 body{margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px;}
.mainContainer{float:left; height:auto; width:100%; max-width:800px; }
.image{float:left; margin-top:0px; width:14.25%; height:auto;}
.storyWrapper{float:left;  width:85.75%; height:auto; min-height:64px; background-color:#f6f6f6; color:#000000;transition:0.2s; }
.storyWrapper:hover{background-color:#c0c0c0; color:#ffffff;}
.headline{text-align:left; padding:6px 6px 6px 6px; font-size:11pt; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial; text-decoration:none;}
```

The link to this page is: http://www.rebelplanetnews.com/newsMenu3.html

As you can see, my issue is.. the text div to the right overlaps the image div to the left on page resize (smaller). I need to prevent that.

Comment: You have an `img` inside a `div`. The `div` is responsive, but the `img` is a fixed size. Is that the plan?

Comment: October 2020. The solution is to forget about `float` and use either flexbox or grid. The three remaining users whose browsers don’t will have to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is not to use a percentage for your headline. The simplest solution is to use the `calc` value, which can be used in all modern browsers.

The following will work:

```
div.storyWrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 114px);
    float: right;
}
```

Here, I have noted that the width of the image is 114px, and set the width of the container to 100% minus that.

I have also floated the container to the right.

Note that `calc` is a little bit fussy. In particular, you need spaces around the `-` operator: `calc(100%-114px)` will not work, at least not in all browsers.

Comment: Documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your actual image isn't shrinking when the .image div is. So .image div will adjust according to its width percentage, but not the image contained within it. If you add a width: 100% to the img element, the image will now shrink along with the div container, and the text div won't overlap.

Comment: I do not want the image to shrink. The only portion I want to shrink is the 'storyWrapper' div. And I only want that div to shrink in width, not height.